# Hardhat - get latest block number in seconds

Tags: javascript, ethereum, hardhat

How to get the latest block number in seconds (TEST_URL = RPC BSC test) :

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(Process.env.TEST_URL);
let timestamp = 0;
// Block Number
provider.getBlockNumber().then(function(blockNumber) {
    timestamp = blockNumber;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```js
// Get the block number
provider.getBlockNumber().then(function(blockNumber) {

    // getBlock returns a block object and it has a timestamp property.
    provider.getBlock(blockNumber).then(function(block) {

        // Assign block.timestamp to timestamp variable
        timestamp = block.timestamp;
    }
});
```